# Recurrence relation for ways to color a circle with two colors such that there can't be two adjacent reds

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> Find the recurrence relation for how many ways there are to color a carousel with a circumference of length $n$ with two colors, red and blue such that no two reds will be adjacent

This is like asking about a string of $A,B$ of length $n$ without $AA$ and it can't start and end with $A$.

So: $a_n=\begin{cases} AB\text{____}B = a_{n-3} \\
 B\text{______}= a_{n-1} \end {cases}$

$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3} \\a_1 = 2, a_2 = 3, a_3 =4 $

For $a_3$ these aren't allowed: $\{AAA, AAB, BAA, ABA\}$ so $2^3-4=4$

Can I do this with the beginning and end of the sequence?

Comment: Your notation is rather nonstandard, but assuming I understand your intentions correctly, how does `ABABBBAB` get counted? Or `BABBA`?

Comment: Yeah I think so, `ABABBBAB` is in the first case and `BABBA` is in the second case no? @HenningMakholm

Comment: @HenningMakholm the string `ABBBA` isn't supposed to be counted here I think.

Comment: Oh I get it now, `ABBBA` is a subsequence of `ABABBBAB`.

Comment: `ABBBA` is _the_ subsequence you need to insert in `AB___B` to make `ABABBBAB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find it most intuitive to start by having two simultaneous recurrences: $p_n$ is the number of valid strings of length $n$ that start with `B` and end with `A`; $q_n$ is the number of valid strings of length $n$ that both start and end with `B`.

We then have
$$ \begin{align} p_n &= q_{n-1} && p_1 = 0 \\
q_n &= p_{n-1} + q_{n-1} && q_1 = 1 \end{align} $$
This gives us
$$ \tag{*} q_n = q_{n-1} + q_{n-2} $$
but what we're really interested in is
$$ c_n = 2p_n + q_n = 2q_{n-1} + q_n $$
(where the `A___B` strings count twice because we can use either the string or its reverse). Because this is a linear combination of $q_n$s it will itself satisfy $\text(*)$.

Comment: I don't understand the last line, is $(*)$ the final answer?

Comment: @kuhaku: Yes, because $q_n$ satisfies that recurrence, and $q_{n-1}$ also satisfies it, so any linear combination of them will again satisfy it.

Comment: Ah I see. That's surprising because it's the same relation as if it was in a line instead of a circle. (so the string is allowed to end in `A`)

Comment: @kuhaku: Yes, the difference is only in the initial values. (In my mind this makes sense, because most of the growth in the number of assignments comes from decisions in the _middle_ of the string, which can't see whether it connects at the end or not, so adding an extra position that is _not_ covered by the boundary conditions should be expected to increase the number of solutions with the same factor (asymptotically) in each case).